# Button_Click is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Why my code does not work? I click on the button in the application and nothing happens. In youtube tutorials it is working very well...
Sorry for my english...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!textBox2.Text.Trim().Equals("") && 
        !textBox3.Text.Trim().Equals("") && 
        !textBox4.Text.Trim().Equals("") && 
        !textBox5.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(idkl,textBox2.Text, 
                textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text);

            idkl++;
        }

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(idkl, 
                textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text);

            idkl++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wypełnij wymagane pola!");
    }
}
```

Thanks for help
Mariusz Ś.

Comment: Did you link this event handler code to the event Click of your button?

Comment: Use debugger and see if your click handler even gets called. Probably you haven't assign it to the appropriate button event.

Comment: Does the method get called at all, or are something else not working?

Comment: Is it possible that you duplicated the code from the youtube tutorial ? If so you have to assign the event to the button in order for it to work. You must go to the properties of your button, select events (the symbol that looks like a flash) and the search for ButtonClick then you double click that field and assign "button1_Click" to it.

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect, i doubt it can build. Second if with `comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0` statement is never ended. Also if there are more than 2 elements in combobox it will do nothing.

Comment: I assign event. Now application always show message:"Wypełnij wymagane pola!" when I click the button...

Comment: Only this button does not working...

Comment: Pranav Singh How I can fix that problem?

Comment: FYI: C# does not have any UI. Please tag with the appropriate UI Framework: `wpf`, `winforms`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You Should have

```
 button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

in your designer or in your code(e g : PageLoad() )

Comment: At first You should clone a row of datagridview,Then fill the cloned row and add it to datagridview :

Answer (score 0):

```
   DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();  

        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_org.Rows.Count; i++)  
        {  
            row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_org.Rows[i].Clone();  
            int intColIndex = 0;  
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv_org.Rows[i].Cells)  
            {  
                row.Cells[intColIndex].Value = cell.Value;  
                intColIndex++;  
            }  
            dgv_copy.Rows.Add(row);  
        }  
        dgv_copy.AllowUserToAddRows = false;  
        dgv_copy.Refresh();
```

Comment: This code copy first row and add it to datagridview, you just need to put your textbox.text into one of the copied row's cell